# Mandrill Handlebar Template does not render / merge with Parse.com object correctly

Tags: templates, parse-platform, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill to send template-based email notifications each time a given Object is created in a Parse.com app.

The Mandrill template (made with Handlebars) uses 2 typical Parse.com object properties:

- objectId --> {{object.objectId}} in the template
- createdAt --> {{object.createdAt}} in the template

The problem is that other object properties, but these don't.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem keeps unsolved. However I had several other problems using the Mandrill api, so I will leave it here for helping others:

*Symptom: None of the other object properties got rendered*

Problem1: used `template_contents` that only support strings, not objects as content

Solution1: use `global_merge_vars`

Problem2: used `global_merge_vars` outside the `message` parameter

**Solution2: use `global_merge_vars` inside the `message` parameter**

*Symptom: every object property gets rendered except `objectId` and `createdAt`*

Problem: still don't know

**Partial Solution: copy `objectId` to `id` in parse**